# Post Status in LinkedIn

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, linkedin-api, hammock

I saw one artcle how to share our status in LinkedIn using c#.
I follow those steps and the code I am using is following...
For this I am using Hammock library.

```
        OAuthCredentials credentials = new OAuthCredentials();

        credentials.Type = OAuthType.AccessToken;
        credentials.ConsumerKey = "****";
        credentials.ConsumerSecret = "*****";
        credentials.Token = "******";
        credentials.TokenSecret = "*********";
        credentials.SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1;
        credentials.ParameterHandling = OAuthParameterHandling.HttpAuthorizationHeader;


        RestClient client = new RestClient();

        client.Authority = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1";
        client.Credentials = credentials;
        client.Method = WebMethod.Put;
        byte[] msg = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Test");
        client.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        client.AddPostContent(msg);


        RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
        request.Path = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/current-status";


 /* ERROR */ RestResponse response = client.Request(request);
```

It's giving me a error "Bad Request." 
How to solve this please help me..?

Comment: @SearchAndResQ Ya I tried but then it's giving error "No method found"